# Xml: best practice to create x-path with parameters

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

What is the best practice to create x-path with parameters?

I have to select xml node where attribute has exact value, something like:

```
XmlNode node = parentNode.SelectSingleNode(
  string.Format("./field1/field2[@attributeName='{0}']", valueRequired));
```

Comment: The issue you have with this kind of code is valueRequired needs to be properly escaped to ensure it does not break the XPATH syntax. Marc Gravell's proposition does not have this problem - although I'm a deep fan of XPATH :)

Comment: We have parametrized SQL queries, but still no parametrized XPath...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The host of the XPath engine can create *variables* that are part of the context. Example of host, providing this facility is XSLT**.

In XSLT one would simply write:

```
field1/field2[@attributeName=$valueRequired]"
```

One way of creating XPath variables and functions in .NET is to use the **[`XsltContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltcontext.aspx)** class and its methods [**`ResolveVariable()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltcontext.resolvevariable.aspx) and **[`ResolveFunction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltcontext.resolvefunction.aspx)**

**Another thing to remember: Never blindly insert user input into a "skeleton" of an XPath expression. Be aware of the possibility for [XPath injection](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xpathinjection.html)**.

Comment: +1 For variable binding recomendation. I was looking for some class but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on whether `valueRequired` is ever going to have a nasty value such as `'`. But for simple values that should work OK.

Otherwise, LINQ-to-XML is quite nice:

```
// where parentNode is XElement
var node = (from el in parentNode.Elements("field1").Elements("field2")
            where (string) el.Attribute("attributeName") == valueRequired
            select el).FirstOrDefault();
```

(replace the `(string)` with other types as necessary)

Here's something similar using LINQ over an XmlElement:

```
var parentNode = node.SelectNodes("./field1/field2[@attributeName]")
        .Cast<XmlElement>()
        .Where(el => el.GetAttribute("attributeName") == valueRequired)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

The other option (without **any** LINQ) is simply looping manually with a foreach.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like that with old XmlDocument code or do you suggest to rewrite that to XDocument / XElement ?

Comment: @Andrew - I'll edit to show something similar with XmlDocument

Comment: How the answer to "best practice to create x-path with parameters" is... use LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

Some times X-Path notation is shorter and clearer than LINQ, in this case I would prefer to use X-Path rather than LINQ. In your case, because you already know the attribute type, it should be easy to decide wheter include quotes or not.

You should consider to use the elements of **System.Xml.XPath**, through the following methods:

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile); 
XElement xmlRoot = XElement.Load(xmlReader);  
xmlReader.Close();  
IEnumerable<XElement> nodes = 
   xmlRoot.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("./field1/field2[@attributeName='{0}']", valueRequired));
```

Comment: Isn't this unnecessarily **more** complex than the example in the original question? Oh, and the arg to `XPathSelectElements` is borked (won't compile).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. You should know what can be in `valueRequired`. If you don't trust in its source, then sanitize it like with any untrusted data.

Also, you don't need to start a relative path with `./`, use just:

```
field1/field2[@attributeName='{0}']
```